# ¿Cómo agregar un IN en consulta para ingresar más de un parámetro desde una variable en metabase?

Tags: entrada, msql

me pueden ayudar indicándome como agregar un filtro que me permita desde una variable de entrada ingresar más de un dato?

```sql
SELECT * from TABLA
WHERE tarea_id in ({{var_tarea}});
```

Donde `var_tarea` es una variable de entrada como texto.

Se puede utilizar un IN?

Answer (score 1):

Si puedes hacerlo:

Por ejemplo en MSSQL pues usar un STRING_SPLIT

```sql
SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.', ' ');
```

y si cambiandolo a un una variable digamos `@data`

```sql
DECLARE
  @data NVARCHAR(50) = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.'
SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@data , ' ');
```

> Ten en cuenta que aca se van a separa pro el que tu ingreses en este caso un  espacio en blanco.

Y ahora todo en conjunto:

```sql
DECLARE
  @data NVARCHAR(50) = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.'


SELECT * from TABLA
WHERE tarea_id in (
  SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@data , ' ')
);
```

> **STRING_SPLIT** esta disponible en las ultimas versiones de MSSQL pero por internet puedes encontrar varias alternativas por si usas versión que no la tenga implementada.

Answer (score 0):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que necesito hacer es leer una variable de metabase que tenga más de un valor, tal como aparece en la imagen.

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).